# How to perform a recursion in bison?

Tags: function, parsing, recursion, bison

i am new at flex/bison . I have already written some rules for functions .My problem here is that when i try to write a rule for a main function(in c) it can contains many functions inside . So , i thought that the best way is to write a recursion rule ,in order to find all the possible functions inside my main .Main function is biult like this:

```
int main() { 

a = readInt(); 
b = readInt(); 

add(a, b);
}
```

I tried this :

```
function_declare_rec:
    function_declare
|   function_declare_rec function_declare 
;
```

but it only prints this :

```
int main(){
  add(a,b);
}
```

and then:

```
function_declare_rec:
    function_declare
|   function_declare function_declare_rec
;
```

but it prints:

```
int main(){
  a = readInt()
}
```

Any help would be valuable!!

Comment: There is no obvious connection between your example and your question. Your `main` function contains no function declaration at all, and your parser prints nothing.

Comment: Both of your bison examples are recursive (left- and right-) and accept the same inputs (just with a different parse tree and reduction order.)

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion is coming from the fact that a function *declaration* is not the same thing as a function *call*. A function declaration consists of a return type, a name, a parenthesized list of parameters, a set of curly braces, and the contents of the function body. A function *call* consists of the name of a function and a parenthesized list of expressions representing its arguments.

Consider making two separate nonterminals, one representing each of these structures. Chances are that they will not be (directly) recursive.